# Expectation of a MM estimator

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, statistical-inference

So I want to calculate the expectation of my estimator to see if it is biased or not.
Data:

$\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}x_i$

$E[\bar{X}]= \frac{\theta}{\theta + 1}$

$\hat{\theta}_{mm}$ = $\frac{\bar{X}}{1-\bar{X}}$

I apparently calculated it wrong:
$E[\hat{\theta}_{mm}]=E[\frac{\bar{X}}{1-\bar{X}}]=\frac{E[\bar{X}]}{1-E[\bar{X}]}$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos added my work

Comment: It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos done

Comment: $E\left[\frac{\bar{X}}{1-\bar{X}}\right]$ will usually not be equal to $\frac{E[\bar{X}]}{1-E[\bar{X}]}$.  The first is the expectation of your method of moments estimator while the second is $\theta$ so the difference is the bias, which will depend on the distribution of $X_i$

Comment: @StubbornAtom well it says the value is not trivial .. it means i cant calculate it ?